Switching apps by typing out letter hints? (like vim hop, or homerow)
I would like a display of all my open dock apps in the middle with letter hints to type to switch to the corresponding app. To quickly switch between any apps in my dock without having to set hotkeys for each of them specifically. Hop.nvim & Homerow show hints, but homerow is slow to load them. Ideally something that looks like this:


Any reason why Command Tab, or Spotlight, isn't enough?

I want to switch to any open app in as few keystrokes as possible. A hotkey to open an app switcher > 2 letters to switch to a given app (the letters can be randomly assigned and not belong to the app name or title) > switch to the app without pressing enter. I don't wanna assign a bunch of hotkeys to specific apps that I don't use often.

I’m not aware of any functionality like this built into the dock or spotlight.
My launch tool of choice is designed to allow one to keep their hands on the keyboard.

https://obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html

It’s got a free trial and is free to use perpetually with a very generous rate limit (imo). You could easily define exactly the key commands you mapped out in the image to launch the apps from the keyboard with this tool. The UI isn’t the same as you describe, though.

Know of no app that will do exactly what you want.
I use rcmd by The Low-Tech Guys to switch between running apps:

https://lowtechguys.com/rcmd/

By pressing the right ⌘ key and the first letter of an open app it will switch to that app. If there are multiple apps with the same first letter, Mail, Music, and Messages for example, repeated presses of right ⌘ M will cycle through them.
rcmd can be configured to show an app switcher something like you are looking for, but you'll still need to cycle through apps with the same initial letter.
